# Invalid memory address passed when calling custom DLL function in Microsoft Access SQL

Tags: c++, vba, ms-access, dll

I would like to call a custom function `Simil(LPCWSTR a, LPCWSTR b)` for computing the [Ratcliff/Obershelp string matching algorithm](http://accessmvp.com/TomVanStiphout/Simil.htm) in Microsoft Access SQL (2019). The function resides in `Simil.dll`. The following is the `dllmain.cpp` file that defines the entry point and which I compile using the Nuwen MinGW Distro.

```cpp
#ifdef __MINGW32__
#include <windows.h>
#endif

extern "C"
{
#include "simil.h"
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    return TRUE;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double Simil(LPCWSTR a, LPCWSTR b) {
    return simil((const wchar_t*)a, (const wchar_t*)b);
}
```

I load the DLL in VBA as follows and it works well in VBA itself.

```vb
Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" _
    (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long

Private Sub Init()
    LoadLibrary(CurrentProject.Path & "/Simil.dll")
    Debug.Print fnSimil(StrConv("TestABC", vbUnicode), StrConv("TestACB", vbUnicode))  ' 0.85..
    Debug.Print fnSimil("TestABC", "TestACB")  ' 0.85..
End Sub
```

However, when calling the function in Microsoft Access SQL the program crashes due to access violation after successfully calling and running the function (up to an instruction which accesses the first argument).

```vb
Public Declare PtrSafe Function fnSimil _
   Lib "Simil" Alias "Simil" _
   (ByVal strOne As String, ByVal strTwo As String) As Double

Private Sub Update() 
    Me![Results].RowSource = "SELECT name from db ORDER BY fnSimil([db.name], ""Test"") DESC"  ' crash!
End Sub
```

In fact, the debugger tells me that the first argument to `Simil` is seemingly always the address `0x0000000000000005`, no matter how I change the SQL query above. The second argument also points to garbage as far as I can tell, but at least it is a valid address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. I used a User Defined Function (UDF) in VBA that I was able to call from the SQL context. This function needs to reside in a module for it to be available in SQL.

```vb
Function fnSimilWrapper(a, b)
    fnSimilWrapper = fnSimil(a, b)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

If doing a 32-bit build make the function WINAPI (__stdcall) as well:

```
extern "C" double WINAPI Simil(LPCWSTR A, LPCWSTR B) { ... }
```

Comment: I did not build it in 32-bit, but 64-bit. Confusingly, in MinGW-w64, both `__MINGW32__` and  `__MINGW64__` are defined ([source](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/discussion/723798/thread/ea355c1f/)). I confirmed the DLL is 64-bit (`PE  d†` at offset `0x110`).